# SQL Server Stored Procedure ON DELETE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with a recursive relationship that has a foreign key constraint for ID and ParentID.

```
MyTable Schema
------------------
ID
Name
ParentID
```

I'm not enforcing the Foreign Key constraint and have to leave the CASCADING to No Action because it would cause cyclic cascades (which is what I want). When I delete a record that has children, I still want to automatically delete all its children (i.e. DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ParentID = THIS_RECORD_I_JUST_DELETED). This would invoke the procedure recursively until all the children and their children were deleted.

How can I write a SQL Server Procedure to do this. I know there is ON UPDATING or ON DELETING type clauses but can't find anything related when I Google it.

Comment: cyclic cascades  are dangerous. I generally avoid them.

Comment: Personally, I would not design a Database that relies on sp's or triggers for hierarchical updates.

Answer (score 0):

Use following query:

In this query selected all rows that must be deleted in first. then update parentId column and then delete them.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteRow(@Id INT)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @IdList TABLE(Id int)

    ;WITH IdList(Id) AS (
        SELECT Id
        FROM YourTable t
        WHERE Id = @Id

        UNION ALL

        SELECT t.Id
        FROM IdList 
        INNER JOIN YourTable t ON t.ParentId = IdList.Id
    )

    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE YourTable
    SET parentId = NULL
    OUTPUT Inserted.Id INTO @IdList
    WHERE Id IN(SELECT Id  FROM IdList)

    DELETE YourTable WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @IdList)
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```